# Scroll page at end of vimeo video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have used jQuery before to creating one-page websites, and am familiar with using page anchors to scroll down the page. However, I'm looking to achieve an effect similar to the one on this website ( http://apps.npr.org/tshirt/#/cotton ). Click the "play" button, and scroll to about 5 seconds before the video ends to see the effect.

How can I trigger jQuery to scroll once the video has 5 seconds remaining?

Or would this be better achieved by setting a delay (which equals the length of the video, minus 5 seconds) on the scroll, for each page. There will only be three videos/pages in total, and this isn't something I'm looking to automate too much for future additions, so creating a simply delay/scroll might do the trick.

Comment: Adding delay is not a reliable solution because you will need to take into account pauses, and user directly moving forward in the video. Simply add event handler for `timeupdate`. This event is fired at every time update ( usually 4 times a sec ) as the video progresses and returns the current video seek time. You can use this time, to trigger scroll when time is right ;)